# how to append a line to all files under a directory?

Tags: ios, macos, awk

I have a directory contains 50 files, what I need to do is append a new text to echo file, such as 'thelastline`, I don't know how to do it in mac os

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i '$athelastline' /path/*.file
```

if you are using bsd sed, the `-i` option would be `-i ''`

```
sed -i '' '$athelastline' /path/*.file
```

Comment: This won't work for empty files, but I think it's acceptable for most use cases.

Comment: @Birei yep.. thanks for pointing it. in fact the easiest is loop through all files, and do a `echo "foo" >> $file`

Answer (score 2):

Find all files in current directory and below and append `lastline` to each:

```
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i '$a lastline' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Under OSX this is probably easiest with `sed`, but you seem to be asking about how to do this with `awk`, so here is a `nawk` compatible way of doing it (assuming you do not have strange characters in your filenames):

```
for f in *; do 
  awk '1; END { print "thelastline" }' "$f" > /tmp/tmpfile
  mv /tmp/tmpfile "$f"
done
```

In case you are using `zsh`, there is a nice idiom for appending something to all files in the current directory:

```
<<<"thelastline" >>*
```

Note that `multios` needs to be enabled.